Supabase Subscribe to channel callback not being called on insert
I want to create a SupabaseService class in TypeScript which implements an interface for easy swapping of DB's. I have created this "subscribe" methods within the class for reference which as you will see fails the test.
static async subscribeToTable(tableName, channelName, event, callback) {
    this.supabase
        .channel(channelName)
        .on('postgres_changes', {
            event,
            schema: 'public',
            table: tableName,
        }, (payload) => {
            callback(payload.new);
        })
        .subscribe();
}

I now try testing this class, and while some work (here is a WORKING test for inserting and deleting rows and to make it clear how the new DB manipulation functions work)
test('inserts a row into a table and deletes', async () => {
        const tableName = 'servers';
        const row = generateServerRow(); // all "generate" methods are local to the test
        await SupabaseService.insertRow(tableName, row);

        // // select the row to verify it was inserted
        const selectedData = await SupabaseService.selectFromTable(tableName, ['*'], {server_id: row.server_id});
        expect(selectedData).toBeTruthy();
        expect(selectedData.length).toBe(1);
        expect(selectedData[0].cpu_cores).toBe(1);
        expect(selectedData[0].ip_address).toBe('0.0.0.0');
        expect(selectedData[0].mac_address).toBe('00:00:00:00:00:00');
        expect(selectedData[0].is_user_server).toBe(false);

        // clean up
        await SupabaseService.deleteRow(tableName, {server_id: row.server_id});

        // verify the row was deleted
        const selectedDataAfterDelete = await SupabaseService.selectFromTable(
            tableName,
            ['*'],
            {server_id: row.server_id});

        expect(selectedDataAfterDelete).toBeTruthy();
        expect(selectedDataAfterDelete.length).toBe(0);
    });

However, this now test fails and I cannot get it to work (it fails at the checking for numSolverQueueRows + 1 line meaning the callback function is not called)
test('subscribes to table insert', async () => {
        let numCalls = 0;
        const currentRows = await SupabaseService.selectFromTable('solver_queue', ['*'], {});
        const {userRow, serverRow, solverRow, modelRow, solverQueueRow} = await setUpSolverQueue(); // also a local method

        await SupabaseService.subscribeToTable('solver_queue', 'room1', SupabaseService.EVENTS.INSERT, (row) => {
            numCalls++;
        });

        const numSolverQueueRows = (await SupabaseService.selectFromTable('solver_queue', ['*'], {})).length;

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

        console.log("checked rows: ", currentRows.map(row => row.model_id));
        // length
        console.log("current rows: ", currentRows.length);

        expect(numCalls).toBe(currentRows.length);

        await SupabaseService.insertRow('solver_queue', solverQueueRow);
        const newNumSolverQueueRows = (await SupabaseService.selectFromTable('solver_queue', ['*'], {})).length;

        // wait 1000 ms
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        expect(newNumSolverQueueRows).toBe(numSolverQueueRows + 1);

        expect(numCalls).toBe(currentRows.length + 1);

        // clean up
        await cleanUpSolverQueue(solverRow, modelRow, serverRow, userRow);
    });

Am I misinterpreting the functionality of Supabase's subscribe to channel? What error am I making for it to not call the callback?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
